# How to change to a different user after SFTP login

Tags: ssh, permissions, osx, sftp, sshfs

The goal:
Use local IDE (IntelliJ PHPStorm 9) to browse & edit remote files via SSH

The obstacle:
My user on the remote machine does not have permissions to read files, which are owned by `otheruser`, but I have access to `sudo su otheruser`.
However, direct login with `otheruser` (`ssh otheruser@remote`) is disabled and modifying the permissions is not possible.

So essentially, what I need:

- For PHPStorm to execute `sudo su otheruser` after it opens SFTP
  connection via its `Deployment > Browse remote host` tool (there doesn't seem to be any option to do that)
- OR, open SSH tunnel, change to `otheruser` and make IDE connect to it
- OR, mount the remote folder locally (my local machine runs OSX) with `sshfs` (or some other tool, that has the ability to change user after login)

Is this possible? If so, how? Or maybe there is some other/better way to achieve this?

Comment: `ForceCommand /usr/bin/sudo -n -u otheruser /usr/libexec/ssh/sftp-server` ?